# C'tor in c++ class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, nested

can I declare new variables, like one of a different class,
in a c'tor?
Assume I have a class named List and a Node (nested in the List class), then I want to do:

```
List::List(int num)
{
Node Nod(num); //creating a new Node which is holding num
List_Head=&Nod; //List_Head is a Node pointer variable of List class
}
```

Once I do that, I get the following **Runtime error**:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Any help?

Comment: this is basic c++, you assign the address of a local (that is, temporary) variable. Once you go out of the c'tor scope, `Nod` is deleted and so is the memory pointed by `List_Head`.

Answer (score 3):

The scope and lifetime of `Nod` you create is limited to the constructor `List::List()` Since it is a local/automatic object.

Once the constructor returns `Nod` does not exist and anything pointing to it(`List_Head`) is a dangling pointer, deferencing it would cause **Undefined Behavior** and most likely a crash.

You should be creating the `Node` on dynamic memory(heap) by calling `new` if you want to refer it beyond the constructor body.

```
List_Head = new Node(num);
```

ideally, You should use some sort of an **smart pointer** instead of raw pointer for `List_Head` so that you don't have to the manual memory management. If you can't you have to call:

```
delete List_Head;
```

after you are done with your usage so as to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: But if I create Node on dynamic memory, it is just a pointer..
Node *nod=new Node;
I want to create not a pointer, but a Node variable and insert NUM to it. How do i do that?

Comment: @user1309152: yes, whats wrong with that? As long as you have a valid pointer pointing to the allocated memory, all is safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that. `Nod` goes out of scope at the end of the constructor (the last `}`), which means its memory gets invalidated, which means that `List_Head` is pointing to invalid memory.

If you want to keep the memory around, you have to use `new`, like

```
List_Head = new Node(num);
```

Just be sure to `delete` what you `new`! But you have to be careful with this! Memory can leak if you don't delete it, or it can be double deleted if you don't handle it right. Specifically, you need to be sure to also implement the destructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator to properly handle the memory you allocate.

Alternatively, you can use smart pointers (such as `std::shared_ptr` if you're using C++11) to handle the deletions for you so you don't leak memory or double delete memory. You may have to still define your copy constructor and assignment operator though, depending on how you want your class to act (because without custom versions of these, you'll get a [shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy) of the object instead of a [deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy), which may not be what you want).

Comment: Thanks, and let's assume I didn't have List_Head. How would I do it then?

Comment: You're pretty stuck then. You can't dynamically add members to classes like that.